# "Ctrl + ." displays "e" character and captures the keyboard shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters

For a few days now I can no longer use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> anywhere (which makes working with Vs Code pretty frustrating). Instead of executing the shortcut an `e` appears. I can then write normally, and when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the `e` disappears. This is similar to the unicode shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, but everything I write after the `e` is not altered after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Have I activated some setting or system Shortcut?

I'm on `Ubuntu Mate 21.10` and have been for several months before the problem appeared.

Comment: Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370022/ubuntu-21-10-keyboard-shortcut-ctrl-changed-how-to-disable-or-change) any help? (also see frabjous answer below re ibus).

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Couple things to try:

Turn it off directly with gsettings. From the terminal, type:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "[]"
```

Or run

```
ibus-setup
```

Look under "Emoji" tab.

You'll need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in emoji-mode to select an emoji.

Comment: Thank you kindly, the very first item worked (for me, Ctrl-; was affecting, rendering (terminal)Emacs commenting out a line failing, blocking the input altogether until ESC is pressed)

Comment: For a newcomer to Linux this wasn't clear that it has to be run in the terminal. Could you edit it to make it clear?

Comment: This worked in 2023 for Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue but the problem was that I didn't understand how it's supposed to work rather than it being broken.

When you press the *Emoji annotation* shortcut key (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> as configured by `ibus-setup`), the "e̲" character that's inserted into the text signals that you have switched from the *regular mode* to the *emoji inserting mode*. Press it again or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch back to the *regular mode* and the "e̲" character disappears.

To insert an emoji, you can use it in two ways:

### 1. Select an emoji from the list (Emoji selector dialog)

1. Press the *Emoji annotation* shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) to switch to the *emoji inserting mode* - the character "e̲" is inserted
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the emoji group selector
3. Using the keyboard, select a group and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to the *emoji selector view*
4. Select an emoji and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert it into the text and switch back to the *regular mode* (the "e̲" character will be replaced by the selected emoji character)

### 2. Type the name or shorthand of the emoji to be inserted

1. Press the Emoji annotation shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) to switch to the *emoji inserting mode* - the character "e̲" is inserted
2. Type the emoji name or its textual representation, e.g. `:)` or `heart`
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to replace the inserted text with the emoji corresponding to the inserted text (the "e̲" character stays there at this point)
4. If you're OK with the inserted emoji, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch back to the *regular mode* (the "e̲" character disappears and the inserted emoji stays in the text)
5. If you don't like the inserted emoji, you can go back to the inserted text by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> (press it again to cancel the emoji mode completely - inserted text including the "e̲" character is removed and you switch back to the *regular mode*) or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again to show the emoji selector with emojis filtered by the inserted text, select the emoji you like and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert it to the text and switch back to the *regular mode*

---

Disclaimer: I have just discovered how it works so it's possible that my description is incomplete or inaccurate.